# Clear Environment Settings in scratchWorkspace

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, environment-variable

I have several mxd files with a bad default geo-processing environment. The current and scratch workspaces are set to a location that no longer exists. I'm trying to use python to clear those settings and reset to ArcGIS default, which is blank, so that the user's environment or default geodatabase will be used. My python script successfully clears the info, but does not save it. How can I fix my script to save the default environment for each mxd? I'm missing something.

```py
import arcpy, os  
Workspace = r"..."  
arcpy.env.workspace = Workspace  
mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")  
print(mxdList)  
for mxd in mxdList:  
    filePath = os.path.join(Workspace, mxd)  
    mapedit = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(filePath)  
    arcpy.ResetEnvironments()  
    arcpy.ClearEnvironment("workspace")  
    arcpy.ClearEnvironment("scratchWorkspace")  
    print(arcpy.env.workspace)  
    print(arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace)  
    mapedit.save()  
    del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is not going to work. You are clearing *Application* level environment settings. These are not stored in the mxd but at the ArcMap level. So you are clearing the application, saving the mxd over itself but you have not cleared the settings held by the mxd.

I have not found a way of clearing these settings using python, so I do not believe it is possible. The only way appears to be manually edit them from the menu option GeoProcessing > Environments...

It may be that these settings held in the mxd are simply not exposed to python.

Comment: Thanks. I was really hoping it would work :( So many mxds to now clean manually. Only some of our mxd template files has this issue, so it seemed to be mxd related, and only manually changing it in each one works. I'll see if ESRI has any additional options.